# How to deal with lots of widgets in Haskell+GTK?

Tags: haskell, gtk

I have a Glade file describing my interface. Its goal is to control a Nec monitor through local network. Therefore there are lots of widgets controlling how the monitor works:

[image]

I need to create the link between what I get/set from/to the monitor and the widgets. This means getting/setting values and attaching functions to widgets.

The `Builder` from GTK library requires to use IO () and cast every widget in order to call specific functions on them. This is kinda boring and add (unnecessary) lines of code.

```
module GUI where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk

data NecControlGUI = NecControlGUI
    { winNecControl :: Window
    , entIPAddress :: Entry
    , btnConnection :: Button
    , cbtVideoInput :: ComboBox
    , cbtPIPInput :: ComboBox
    , sclSharpness :: Scale
    , sclContrast :: Scale
    , sclBrightness :: Scale
    , sclBlackLevel :: Scale
    , sclColorTemperature :: Scale
    , cbtGamma :: ComboBox
    , sclBalance :: Scale
    , sclTreble :: Scale
    , sclBass :: Scale
    , sclVolume :: Scale
    , cbtLanguage :: ComboBox
    , sclMenuDisplayTime :: Scale
    }

loadGUI :: String -> IO NecControlGUI
loadGUI guiPath = do
    bdr <- builderNew

    builderAddFromFile bdr guiPath

    window <- builderGetObject bdr castToWindow "winNecControl"
    ipaddress <- builderGetObject bdr castToEntry "entIPAddress"
    connection <- builderGetObject bdr castToButton "btnConnection"
    videoinput <- builderGetObject bdr castToComboBox "cbtVideoInput"
    pipinput <- builderGetObject bdr castToComboBox "cbtPIPInput"
    sharpness <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclSharpness"
    contrast <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclContrast"
    brightness <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclBrightness"
    blacklevel <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclBlackLevel"
    colortemperature <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclColorTemparature"
    gamma <- builderGetObject bdr castToComboBox "cbtGamma"
    balance <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclBalance"
    treble <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclTreble"
    bass <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclBass"
    volume <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclVolume"
    language <- builderGetObject bdr castToComboBox "cbtLanguage"
    menudisplaytime <- builderGetObject bdr castToScale "sclMenuDisplayTime"

    return NecControlGUI
        { winNecControl = window
        , entIPAddress = ipaddress
        , btnConnection = connection
        , cbtVideoInput = videoinput
        , cbtPIPInput = pipinput
        , sclSharpness = sharpness
        , sclContrast = contrast
        , sclBrightness = brightness
        , sclBlackLevel = blacklevel
        , sclColorTemperature = colortemperature
        , cbtGamma = gamma
        , sclBalance = balance
        , sclTreble = treble
        , sclBass = bass
        , sclVolume = volume
        , cbtLanguage = language
        , sclMenuDisplayTime = menudisplaytime
        }
```

Is there a way to automate this part?

I heard of LGtk, but is it the only way to do it?

**Edit 2016-09-20 1**

I tried to go the applicative way, but it doesn't seem that Haskell like combining applicative IO ? (but it's probably me)

```
module NecControlGUI where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk

data NecControlGUI = NecControlGUI
    { adjBalance :: Adjustment
    , winNecControl :: Window
    }

loadNecControlGUI :: String -> IO NecControlGUI
loadNecControlGUI guiPath = do
    bdr <- builderNew
    builderAddFromFile bdr guiPath
    let bget = builderGetObject bdr
    NecControlGUI <$> bget castToAdjustment "adjBalance"
                  <*> bget castToWindow "winNecControl"
```

Compiling outputs the following errors:

```
.../src/NecControlGUI.hs:16:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Adjustment’ with ‘Window’
      Expected type: IO Window
        Actual type: IO Adjustment
    • In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘bget castToWindow "winNecControl"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        NecControlGUI <$> bget castToAdjustment "adjBalance"
        <*> bget castToWindow "winNecControl"
      In the expression:
        do { bdr <- builderNew;
             builderAddFromFile bdr guiPath;
             let bget = builderGetObject bdr;
             NecControlGUI <$> bget castToAdjustment "adjBalance"
             <*> bget castToWindow "winNecControl" }

.../src/NecControlGUI.hs:16:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Window’ with ‘Adjustment’
      Expected type: GObject -> Adjustment
        Actual type: GObject -> Window
    • In the first argument of ‘bget’, namely ‘castToWindow’
      In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘bget castToWindow "winNecControl"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        NecControlGUI <$> bget castToAdjustment "adjBalance"
        <*> bget castToWindow "winNecControl"
```

**Edit 2016-09-20 2**

If I get rid of the `let bdr = ...` statement, everything works as expected.

Comment: Two immediate improvements would be to define `bget = builderGetObject bdr` and stop defining temporary names that are only used once. `return NecControlGUI { winNetControl = bget castToWindow "winNecControl", ...}`

Comment: Hm, not sure, but I don't think LGtk supports Glade files, you would have to define the GUI from scratch with LGtk syntax. I created some fairly complex GUIs with Glade and did lots of this stuff with copy-paste and search/replace. Sure, it's boring, but somehow you have to relate the content of the glade file to some types and values. If you have only the standard case of getting something out of the glade file and putting it into a record field and you have a default naming convention in Glade, you could write a Haskell code generator, but if that's worth it, you have to decide...

Comment: @chepner I can’t go without temporary names because `builderGetObject` returns a monadic value while the record structure works with pure value.

Comment: @MichaelO I thought of writing a templatehaskell program which could take a Glade file as input and generate the corresponding Haskell code, but I hoped this has already been done :-)

Comment: Ah, true; I was really thinking of an answer like `NecControlGUI <$> bget castToWindow "winNecControl" <*> bget castToEntry "entIPAddress" <*> ...`, but that doesn't let you include the field names for readability.

Comment: @chepner Ah, true ; I forgot the applicative way! :o) This way is interesting as it saves 33% of lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not what you are looking for, but it is shorter. Use the `Applicative` instance to combine the calls to `builderGetObject` with the data constructor.

```
module GUI where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk

data NecControlGUI = NecControlGUI
    { ...
    }

loadGUI :: String -> IO NecControlGUI
loadGUI guiPath = do
    bdr <- builderNew

    builderAddFromFile bdr guiPath

    let bget = builderGetObject bdr

    NecControlGUI <$> bget castToWindow "winNecControl"
                  <*> bget castToEntry "entIPAddress"
                  <*> bget castToButton "btnConnection"
                  <*> bget castToComboBox "cbtVideoInput"
                  <*> bget castToComboBox "cbtPIPInput"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclSharpness"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclContrast"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclBrightness"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclBlackLevel"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclColorTemparature"
                  <*> bget castToComboBox "cbtGamma"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclBalance"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclTreble"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclBass"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclVolume"
                  <*> bget castToComboBox "cbtLanguage"
                  <*> bget castToScale "sclMenuDisplayTime"
```

Comment: I tried the applicative way but it doesn't seem to work, thought I don't know really why :-/

Comment: What happens if you switch from record syntax to "regular" syntax: `data NecControlGUI = NecControlGUI Adjustment Window`?

Comment: Exactly the same ! Could it be that the use of cast functions by builderGetObject is what causes the problem ?

Comment: I don't know. Something too subtle for me to figure out is going on. I mean, `builderGetObject bdr castToWindow` has type `String -> IO Window`, right?

Comment: The signature of builderGetObject is `(GObjectClass cls, GlibString string) => Builder -> (GObject -> cls) -> string -> IO cls`, once the cast function set, the final type can be determined.

Comment: I found where the problem came from : it’s the `let bget = builderGetObject bdr` that causes the problem. If I do not use it, keeping every `builderGetObject bdr`, everything goes as expected !